# How to Create Popup in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: popup, xamarin.forms

I m new to Xamarin.Forms in which I have to create a popup which contain two Entry "Name" and "Age" and  two button "Ok" and "Cancel" in click of "Ok" I have to take the value.

Please help me out how i can create the popup with code?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: using DisplayActionSheet  i used but didn't help me out

Answer (score 2):

Try this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs/

> A cross platform library that allows you to call for standard user dialogs from a shared/portable library. Supports Android, iOS, and Windows Phone 8

This is the github repo where you can find instructions and examples: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Comment: I used this package for confirmation, error, info messages etc but can you explain better how do you use to create a functional popup like original question?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to, to use the XLabs PopUp-Control (I use it in my App). 
You will find a documentation (how to use it) here: [How to use XLabs PopUp-Control](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33587/how-to-use-a-listview-in-a-scrollview-with-xlabs-popup-control#latest)

And a documentation how to install and setup XLabs (if you don't already use it) here: [How to install and setup XLabs](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35991/how-to-install-setup-and-use-xlabs#latest)